# zend form headscript

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a Zend_Form which I reuse in different controllers. This form requires a javascript file.

How can I add a link to the javascript inside the form object?

From the view helper I can use headScript(), but inside the form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('ViewRenderer');
$view = $viewRenderer->getView();
$view->headScript();
```

anywhere :)

or ever simpler. `Zend_Form` have method `getView()`

**UPD:** one more way :)

```
$view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
$view->headScript();
```

Comment: getView() of Zend_Form didn't work for some reason, but your solution does. thanks.